# Is there a python function/package for watershed delineation with netcdf files as input?

Tags: python, netcdf, watershed

I have a netcdf file with an equidistant x y grid with UTM coordinates and several variables. I would like to define catchment areas via a watershed delineation function. I found some function or packages (e.g. [pysheds](http://mattbartos.com/pysheds/)) but they all take tif files as input. I tried to convert my netcdf file to tif but then the coordinates don't seem to match the original file perfectly.
So I would like to use my netcdf file as an input. What is the best way to do this?